# jQuery first and last of given character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to be able to select the first and last instances of a given character(s) within a span element.

e.g.

```
<span class="foo">hello (this is hello)</span>
```

I want to be able to find the first bracket and the last bracket within this span and append a class them so the output might be:

```
<span class="foo">hello <span class="bar">(this is hello)</span></span>
```

Is this possible? I've looked at `first` in jQuery but it seems to only work for selecting elements rather than characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex :

```
$('.foo').html(function(_, html){
     return html.replace(/\((.*)\)/, '<span class="bar">($1)</span>')
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/abugil/1/edit) (click "Run with JS)

If you want to deal with more than one bracked group, use

```
$('.foo').html(function(_, html){
     return html.replace(/\(([^\)]*)\)/g, '<span class="bar">($1)</span>')
});
```

Comment: Can you provide documentation for that `function(_, html){` you used?

Comment: It's [this one from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/). `_` is just a variable name, I could have used `html(function(i, html)` but I like to use `_` for unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript provides native methods for this. Strings have an `indexOf()` method that returns the location of the first instance of a given string or character and a `lastIndexOf()` method that returns the last instance. E.g.:

```
var firstE = "Hello, Ben!".indexOf('e'); // firstE = 1
var lastE = "Hello, Ben!".lastIndexOf('e'); //lastE = 8
```